# Complex sub-string replace query SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have the following table containing path info:

I need to replace the DIRECTORY_NAME value in the PATH field with the NEW_DIR_NAME value recursively.

sample table:

PATH                                                  |DIRECTORY_NAME                   |NEW_DIR_NAME 
...............................................................................................................
\folder1\folder2\2a                          | folder2\2a                                  | folder2/2a 
\folder1\folder2\2a\folder3              | folder3                                       | folder3 
\folder1\folder2\2a\folder4              |   folder4                                       | folder4 
\folder1\folder2\2a\folder4\2a\2b    | 2a\2b                                         | 2a/2b 
...............................................................................................................
The result would look like this:
* changes are in bold

NEW_PATH 
...............................................................................................................
\folder1\ **folder2/2a** 
\folder1\ **folder2/2a**\folder3 
\folder1\ **folder2/2a**\folder4 
\folder1\ **folder2/2a**\folder4\ **2a/2b** 
...............................................................................................................

database is Oracle.

using the **select replace(PATH, DIRECTORY_NAME, NEW_DIR_NAME)** function will yield the folowing (not the solution):

\folder1\ **folder2/2a** 
\folder1\folder2\2a\ **folder3** 
\folder1\folder2\2a\ **folder4** 
\folder1\folder2\2a\folder4\ **2a/2b**

Comment: Does it matter what order the replaces are done? i.e. what if a string has the value `\folder1\folder3\2a\2b` and your second row (reference=`folder3`) had replace_with=`folder2`? The answer may be ambiguous.

Comment: yes, the replaces are done in order. "STRING" is sorted.

Comment: I'm sorry, now that makes even less sense. "STRING" is the input data, what does sorting it do?

Comment: Maybe if I provide some context to the issue it may be clearer. "STRING" is a directory path. So when sorted, the field shows directories and sub-directories. Unfortunately some directories have been named using "/". for example "folder2/2a" is one directory not two. By reversing the "/" the end users can easily see where each directory is.

Comment: I've updated the original question to use more valid field names.

Answer (score 1):

Please tell me your field name isn't really `STRING`. Anyways, here's the code you need, based on the supplied field names.

```
SELECT REPLACE(STRING,REFERENCE,REPLACE_WITH)
```

Comment: No the field name isnt really string ;)

Unfortuately, the replace function only replaces the current record. I need it to grab the reference field and replace it in every record where the reference is found.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your data.  Your table posits a one-to-one relationship between PATH and DIRECTORY_NAME, and hence with NEW_DIR_NAME.  But according to your required output this is clearly not so.  The DIRECTORY_NAME appears in multiple values of PATH.

So what you need to do is run the `replace()` statement for every combination where  `DIRECTORY_NAME != NEW_DIR_NAME`

```
for lrec in ( select DIRECTORY_NAME, NEW_DIR_NAME 
              from your_table 
              where DIRECTORY_NAME != NEW_DIR_NAME )
loop

    update your_table
    set  path = replace(PATH, lrec.DIRECTORY_NAME, lrec.NEW_DIR_NAME)
    ;
end loop;
```

This is not a particularly efficient approach but presumably this is a one-off exercise.